# Preparing for the End - Riddle

Tags: riddle, word

> This is the end. 
>   I knew it was coming. 
>   All of my ends are tied up, I'm ready. 
>   Only a few more minutes to spend.
>
> I blame you for this. 
>   You killed the messenger. 
>   I strained and cried out, "please!" 
>   Oh, all the warnings you dismiss!
>
> So let the world fall. 
>   No reason to believe I need it. 
>   My parents gave me to you, **for** you. 
>   Worthless to you after all...
>
> What is this? My heart beat?
>   Are you giving me life?
>   Now I can give you answers, make you smile! 
>   Thank you, soon I'll have enough to eat.

Who/What am I?

Hint 1:

> My generation and the generation before me came from the same parents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you...

> A smartphone with a low battery?

This is the end. 
I knew it was coming. 
All of my ends are tied up, I'm ready. 
Only a few more minutes to spend.

> It knows when it is about to die and what services to stop.

I blame you for this. 
You killed the messenger. 
I strained and cried out, "please!" 
Oh, all the warnings you dismiss!

> The user (you) is the reason why the phone is dying and will just dismiss the battery life warnings. A phone is also a "messenger".

So let the world fall. 
No reason to believe I need it. 
My parents gave me to you, for you. 
Worthless to you after all...

> The phone was made by a group of people and machines: made for the user. The phone is depressed that even after that, you are killing it.

What is this? My heart beat?
Are you giving me life?
Now I can give you answers, make you smile! 
Thank you, soon I'll have enough to eat.

> The user plugged in the phone after or just before it died. It's processor's heart is beating again. The smartphone is used to find answers online or entertain the user. Once it's battery is fed, it tells the user.

Comment: You got it. Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 2):

Could you be

> a child's tooth?

*This is the end.

    I knew it was coming.

    All of my ends are tied up, I'm ready.

    Only a few more minutes to spend.*

> The milk tooth is about to fall out. Its roots are no longer holding it in the mouth, and it's ready to leave and face its end.

*I blame you for this.

    You killed the messenger.

    I strained and cried out, "please!"

    Oh, all the warnings you dismiss!*

> Pressure on the milk tooth from eating?

*So let the world fall.

    No reason to believe I need it.

    My parents gave me to you, for you.

    Worthless to you after all...*

> The milk tooth was useful to the child in earlier life, but now it's worthless and needs to go.

*What is this? My heart beat?

    Are you giving me life?

    Now I can give you answers, make you smile!

    Thank you, soon I'll have enough to eat.*

> This is the new permanent tooth: erupting into the mouth with its roots in place, becoming part of the child's smile and helping to eat their food.

Comment: This was definitely not what I had in mind, but it does fit really well. Tempted to accept it now.